# Как отобразить значок рубля или доллара при выводе информации с API

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Вывожу данные с апи через js fetch() функцию

```
fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((nft) => {
        document.getElementById('nft').innerHTML = `${nft.map(function (token) {
            return `
                                        <div class="df df_1">
                <p class="card-text fz-14">Цена</p>
                <b class="fz-16">${token.price.value} ${token.price.currency}</b>
            </div>

                <div class="blogger">
                    <img class="card-img-blog" src="${token.creator.img_url}" alt="">
                        <p class="color-2 fz-10">Проверено &#10003</p>
    
                </div>
            `
        }).join('')}`;
    })
```

При выводе в ${token.price.currency} выводится либо usd либо rub, хотел бы спросить какую функцию сделать, чтобы при usd выводился значок $, а при рубле значок &#8381 (то есть рубля).

А также строчку Проверено &#10003 нужно заменить следующим образом: в json документе это значение либо true, либо false. Как сделать чтобы на страницу выводило зелёным цветом (Проверено &#10003(значок галочки) при true, и красным цветов - не проверено &#10060 при false

Comment: "Как сделать чтобы на страницу выводило зелёным цветом (Проверено &#10003(значок галочки) при true, и красным цветов - не проверено &#10060 при false" Тернарный оператор?

Comment: Тернарный оператор это ответ на вопрос? или в файле json как записано?

Comment: Если в json, то там  "verified"=true or "verified"=false

Comment: Скорее как ответ на вопрос, не знаю зачем вопрос поставил.

Comment: @OliverPatterson почитал документацию, так и не смог реализовать, можно у вас попросить примерный код

Comment: Не знаю насколько будет лаконично, но допустим ```token.verified ? '<p class="color-2 fz-10">Проверено &#10003</p>' : <p class="color-3 fz-10">Проверено &#10060</p>``` color поменяете на то, которое у вас. И я не понимаю смысла оборачивать ваш map в апострофы.

Comment: @OliverPatterson спасибо, работает, а чтобы доллар и евро на значок доллара и евро

Comment: Так же через ? <p>Р</p>' : <p>$</p>

Comment: currency = "usd" ? '$' : 'P' не работает

Comment: Всё, сделал! если что нужно ==

Comment: Если у вас только рубли и доллары, то думаю сойдет, если есть еще что-то, то лучше вынести в объект.